# Tkinter variable definition, which is more desirable?

Tags: python, variables, tkinter

I am new to Tkinter and I was wondering which of the following way to set variables is more desirable:

```
class App():
    def __init__(self,master):
        self.var1 = StringVar()
    <filler>
    def openFile(self,button_type):
        name = tkFileDialog.askopenfilename()
        if button_type == 1:
            self.var1.set(name)
```

or

```
class App():
    def __init__(self,master):
        self.var1 = ""
    <filler>
    def openFile(self,button_type):
        name = tkFileDialog.askopenfilename()
        if button_type == 1:
            self.var1 = name
```

The first option is what I found in the effbot documentation (http://effbot.org/tkinterbook/variable.htm) but the second option is what I would normally do. My biggest question is why would 1 be preferred over the other?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Tkinter variables like StringVar are commonly used to track the change of its values or to pass them as the `variable` or `textvariable` option for creating some widgets. From the section *"When to use the Variable Classes"* of the page you refer to:

> Variables can be used with most entry widgets to track changes to the entered value. The Checkbutton and Radiobutton widgets require variables to work properly.
>
> Variables can also be used to validate the contents of an entry widget, and to change the text in label widgets.

So in your case the natural solution would be the second one: it looks like you want to store the result of `askopenfilename()` like you would do with the result of another statement, but not use it to interact with the text of a widget or track if the value of the StringVar has changed (since you are calling that function, you already know when it is going to be updated).